# Получение информации и управление плеером AIMP в программе на python

Tags: python, бот

Пишу простенького бота для твича, который будет скипать песни по команде !skip, в качестве проигрывателя выбрал AIMP. Для этого надо, чтобы хотя бы половина пользователей ввела эту команду, каждую новую песню счетчик сбрасывается.
Собственно мне надо иметь возможность узнать название текущего трека и пропустить трек. Крайне не хочется учить delphi для написания плагина для AIMP, можно ли обойтись только python'ом?

Comment: Еще есть ControlPlugin для AIMP. Он создает веб интерфейс. Потом с питона, думаю, можно посылать запросы на этот веб-интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется можно попробовать имитировать нажатие клавиш следующий трек/предыдущий трек. Эти клавиши точно поддерживаются современными операционными системами. Вот [библиотечка](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) написанная на питоне.
Вот такой код делает то, что нужно. И без привязки к плееру.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('nexttrack')
pyautogui.press('prevtrack')
```

На OS X правда у меня треки не переключились, на Windows думаю что должно работать.

**UPD**: есть еще специализированная [библиотека для AIMP](https://epocdotfr.github.io/pyaimp/) - использует WinAPI

Comment: А что насчет получения названия текущей песни?

Comment: посмотрите на https://epocdotfr.github.io/pyaimp/

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, прямо то что нужно!